# Model extra calculated attribute get removed when we pass model object to any other function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am calculating extra attribute and assigning that attribute to the Eloquent model. And I am passing that object to other function which accepts that model object only but inside that function, I am not able to access extra value which I have calculated before.

Here is my code.

```
 $order = Order::find(201);
 $order->setAttribute('redemption_end_date','anydate');
```

Now I am passing this order object to other function which accepts an only order model object.

```
function printOrder(Order $o){
    dd($o->redemption_end_date);
}
```

So inside that function when I am trying to access that attribute which I have calculated before, it shows me as `null`.

How can I pass the object without losing data?

Comment: This should work fine. I suspect your problem is more related to how you're fetching or handling the model, not the `setAttribute()` portion. Or, may have a conflict if you're using a mutator or type cast. Feel free to share more code for further assistance!

Comment: @AkenRoberts  so my code is to pass this order object into the notification  and inside a notification, I am not able to access custom attribute

Comment: @AkenRoberts is there any way we can connect so i can show you my code